# Send file to server via retrofit2 as object

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to send an *audio file* to a server with `retrofit2`. I followed [this](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server) tutorial but the file is not in the format the server accepts. Based on this tutorial I tried the following:

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
MultipartBody.Part audio = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", "file", requestBody);
```

and the interface:

```
 @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
 @Multipart
 @POST("app/")
 Call<JResponse> upload(@Part("file") RequestBody file);
```

But, the `file:` attribute is not sent. (If I change `@Part` with `@Body` it exists but then there is another problem)

I want to know how to send a file in following format? Should I convert audio file to `base64` format?

```
{ 'file' : audio_file }
```

Comment: you need to show more code ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For finding How to send your file to Server via **Retroit** following steps may solve your problem:

1- Install [PostMan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en).

2- In PostMan select  `Post` and paste `URL` then go to `Body` tab and choose `form-data`.

3- In `Key`'s part write server file name and In `Value`'s part set type as *File* and upload desire file.

[image]

4- Click in **Send** and then **Generate code**.

5- Now you have something like following:

[image]

6- Now just one step remain go to your retrofit service and paste info like (In my case I want to upload `audio.mp3`) :

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("app/")
    Call<JResponse> upload(@Part("file\"; filename=\"audio.mp3\" ") RequestBody file);
```

And request body would be something like:

```
File file = new File("YOUR_PATH");
RequestBody temp = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
```

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960627/android-retrofit-design-patterns/36963162#36963162) pattern and send it with:

```
 ServiceHelper.getInstance().sendAudio(temp).enqueue(new Callback<JResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JResponse> call, Response<JResponse> response) {
                Log.e("test", "onResponse: tst");

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("test", "onResponse: tst");

            }
        });
```