# @Part parameters can only be used with multipart encoding. (parameter #8)

Tags: android, retrofit, multipartentity

Before I post this question here, I have tried to add `@Multipart` above interface method And searching in stackoverflow still cannot find similar with my problem.

In this case, I try to send image using `TypedFile` to server. My interface method look like this :

```
 @Headers({"Content-type: application/json"})
    @POST("/user/change")
    void postChange(@Query("name") String name, @Query("email") String  email, @Query("password") String password, @Query("phone") String phone, @Query("user_id") String userId, @Query("address[]") String[] listAddress, @Query("head[]") String[] head, @Part("photo_profile") TypedFile photoProfile, @Body TypedInput jsonObject, Callback<ReceiveDTO> callback);
```

**EDIT**

In that method we can see `@Part` and `@Body`. If i add `@Multipart` above the method, it will we throw an error `@Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #9)`

I am using **Retrofit 1.9**

Comment: I would suggest follow the example here - https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server using multipart and then edit question with the problem you are facing

Answer (score 80):

For anyone with the same issue, make sure to add the `@Multipart` annotation above your `@POST/@PUT`. I had the same error and my problem was just that I was missing that `@Multipart` annotation.

Answer (score 15):

We use **@Query** only with `Get` Request and in fact **@Query** append parameters at the end of URL, See [Document](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html) examples.

If you need to send user profile to server, Use `MultiPart`:

> Multipart parts use one of Retrofit's converters or they can implement
>   RequestBody to handle their own serialization.

For example in following piece of code we can send Profile photo with some description to server:

```
@Multipart
@PUT("user/photo")
Call<User> updateUser(@Part("photo") RequestBody photo, @Part("description") RequestBody description);
```

You can even add more additional attributes with @Part. See complete example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39078192/send-file-to-server-via-retrofit2-as-object/39108171#39108171) which step by step explained how to do this.

**Edit**: As JackWarthon explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21423093/1462770), The **@Body** annotation defines a single request body.

```
interface Foo {
  @POST("/jayson")
  FooResponse postJson(@Body FooRequest body);
}
```

Comment: I still got an error `@Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #9)`. It because there is `@Body` in last parameter.