# Retrofit2 : How to upload image with JSONObject in android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to post `JSONObject` with one image which is taken by camera run time. 
how to post an Image using retrofit in android.
This is my **Interface**

```
 @Multipart
@POST("/upload")
Call<Response> getDetails(@Part("empsno") String  empsno,
                                @Part("time")String deliveryTime,
                                @Part("uploadFile") MultipartBody.Part part,
                                @Part("remarks")String remarks,
                                @Part("receiver")String receivedBy,
                                @Part("Address")String ipAddress
                                );
```

code i used to **upload image with other details**

```
 JSONObject oJSONObject = new JSONObject();
        oJSONObject.put("empsno", strEmpsno);
        oJSONObject.put("time", strtime);
        oJSONObject.put("remarks", strRemarks);
        oJSONObject.put("receiver", strReceiver);
        oJSONObject.put("Address", straddress);
        oJSONObject.put("uploadFile", imageFolderPath + "/" + imageName);

RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("uploadFile", file.getName(), requestFile);

xInterface interface = retrofit.create(xInterface.class);
Call<Response> podResponsecall = interface.getDetails(strEmpsno, strtime,
                body, strRemarks, strReceiver, straddress);


  podResponsecall.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<Response> response) {
                String val = response.body() + "";
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + val);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
```

**Output** - onFailure: JSON must start with an array or an object.

I don't know weather this is right or wrong. Please help me to post some images as well as other details using Retrofit2 beta 3.

Comment: try ro replace RequestBody in all paramater rather than String

Comment: got my point? ?

Comment: and how to request the file in java? like this  `RequestBody xemp = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), strEmpsno);
            MultipartBody.Part emp = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("empsno",xemp);`

Comment: i edited my answer check it

Comment: did you try this answer on stackoverflow.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38800960/3678308

Comment: @Javacoder I tried it now , but getting null in response body

Comment: your file is uploaded @AMANSINGH?

Comment: @VishalPatoliya - no still getting null value

Comment: this code 100% working.. for me

Comment: @Javacoder - can you pls explain ("profile_pic\"; filename=\"pp.png\" ")?

Comment: profile_pic is key of image and filename=\"pp.png\"  format of image...

Comment: @Javacoder - now I'm getting response.isSuccess = true but null value in response

Comment: check your server response from server side

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39078192/send-file-to-server-via-retrofit2-as-object/39108171#39108171 see this may help you

Comment: @Amir - now i got what i was looking for. that postman tutorial helped me. Actually i was working with wrong response pojo class

Answer (score 3):

Service.class :

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("upload")
    Call<Void> upload(@Part("model") RequestBody model,  @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

Retrofit 2 part :

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
    RequestBody modelBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), gson.toJson(modelPojo));
    RequestBody reqFileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part mPart1 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file","name",reqFileBody);
```

Java Spring :

```
   @PostMapping(value="/upload" ,consumes = {"multipart/form-data","application/json"})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadImagebyEmail(@RequestPart("model") Object model,@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile uploadfile  ) throws IOException {
    return //codes here...   
    }
```

Comment: is it possible to send only one POJO containing Multipart Image and other Parameters like String? If it;s possible, how can i do it?

Comment: You may dispatch images as a base64 string in an object otherwise i do not know any way.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
@Multipart
@POST("/upload")
Call<ResponseBody> getDetails(@Part("empsno") RequestBody empsno,
                                @Part("time")RequestBody deliveryTime,
                                @Part("uploadFile") MultipartBody.Part part,
                                @Part("remarks")RequestBody remarks,
                                @Part("receiver")RequestBody receivedBy,
                                @Part("Address")RequestBody ipAddress
                                );
```

And also in

```
Call<ResponseBody> podResponsecall = interface.getDetails(strEmpsno, strtime,
                body, strRemarks, strReceiver, straddress);
```

Comment: RequestBody - is it pojo class?

Comment: but here i'm using here **strEmpsno** is in string format

Comment: all i need to change it into RequestBody like             RequestBody empsno = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data") , strEmpsno);

Comment: I tried the way you suggest but getting null in response.body()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122656/discussion-between-vishal-patoliya-and-aman-singh).