# How do I use Retrofit instead of Volley to send an image to my server?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

How should I implement retrofit into this code to send an image to the server instead of using Volley? I'm a little confused as I'm a bit new to Java/Android. I would like some guidance on how to achieve this using Retrofit as Volley doesnt seem to be working.

I'm basically sending a base64 string of an image to my server along with the image name and a few other things later on. I also need to retrieve the response from my server and display it on my app. Volley seemed to do that easily, not sure about Retrofit.

Thanks in advance

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageButton ImageButton;
private String encoded_string, image_name;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private File file;
private Uri file_uri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.camera);
    ImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            getFileUri();
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,file_uri);
            startActivityForResult(i,10);
        }
    });
}

private void getFileUri() {
    image_name = "testing123.jpeg";
    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile(), image_name);

    file_uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        new Encode_image().execute();
    }
}

private class Encode_image extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids){

       bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_uri.getPath());
       ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);

       byte[] array = stream.toByteArray();
       encoded_string = Base64.encodeToString(array,0);
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid){
       makeRequest();
   }
}

private void makeRequest() {
    final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String URL = "http://128.199.77.211/server/connection.php";
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    mTextView.setText(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("encoded_string", encoded_string);
            map.put("image_name", image_name);

            return map;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39108171/1462770 maybe helpful

Answer (score 3):

Using Retrofit 2, you need to use either OkHttp’s RequestBody or MultipartBody.Part classes and encapsulate your file into a request body. Let’s have a look at the interface definition for file uploads.

```
public interface FileUploadService {  
    @Multipart
    @POST("upload")
    Call<ResponseBody> upload(@Part("description") RequestBody description,
                              @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
}
```

**in Java file**

```
private void uploadFile(Uri fileUri) {  
    // create upload service client
    FileUploadService service =
            ServiceGenerator.createService(FileUploadService.class);

    // https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java
    // use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri
    File file = FileUtils.getFile(this, fileUri);

    // create RequestBody instance from file
    RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    MultipartBody.Part body =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile);

    // add another part within the multipart request
    String descriptionString = "hello, this is description speaking";
    RequestBody description =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), descriptionString);

    // finally, execute the request
    Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload(description, body);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call,
                               Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.v("Upload", "success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Upload error:", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm really confused, i dont know how to implement this.

Comment: @RQ14 you must reffer retrofit tutorial

Comment: I'm struggling to implement it with my code. Especially with the camera intent.

Answer (score 1):

Create `MultipartBody.Part` object from your image.

```
File imageIdCard = new File(image_path);
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), imageIdCard);
MultipartBody.Part bodyImage = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image_id", imageIdCard.getName(), requestFile);
```

and upload it

```
@Multipart
@POST("url")
Call<JsonObect> getResponse(@Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```