# Android: Retrofit 2 can't file upload

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to upload a file using Retrofit 2 but it is not working.

The files I am attempting to upload is an image or doc/docx type.  I validate that the file exists prior to upload.  I have also validated that the server information is correct.

```
 MultipartBody.Builder b = new MultipartBody.Builder()
       .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
       .addFormDataPart("title", builder.getTitle()) 
       .addFormDataPart("status", String.valueOf(builder.getStatus()));

b.addFormDataPart("file_f", file1.getName(), 
       RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file1));
b.addFormDataPart("file_s", file2.getName(), 
       RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file2));
return b.build();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39108171/1462770 maybe helpful.

Comment: What's the error?