# Cannot request a post using multipart

Tags: android, retrofit, multipart

I am executing a post type request using Multipart. The problem is because I keep getting two errors

1) 500

2) 422 Unprocessable Entity

Everything works in the postman
[image]

Api only accepts music files.So I added a default file so as not to constantly choose a new one

```
RequestBody body = 
             RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/type"),file);
MultipartBody.Builder builder = new 
MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
builder.addPart(body);
GeoService.saveSound(builder.build(), SoundResponseCallback,  
getAuthToken());
```

and my interface which

```
@Multipart
@POST("audios")
Call<SoundResponse> saveSound(
          @Part("audio[file] ; filename=audio.mp3")RequestBody file,
          @Query("auth_token") String authToken);
```

I would appreciate any help.

and I found it [Send file to server via retrofit2 as object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39078192/send-file-to-server-via-retrofit2-as-object)

Comment: what's the error in logcat

Answer (score 0):

You must send MultipartBody.Part type of parameter in your API

Try this:

```
@Multipart
@POST("audios")
Call<SoundResponse> saveSound(
      @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
      @Query("auth_token") String authToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
@Part("audio[file] ; filename=audio.mp3")RequestBody file,
```

to

```
@Part MultipartBody.Part audioFile,
```

Also make sure that you have enabled the necessary READ WRITE storage permissions

Answer (score 0):

```
@Multipart
@POST("audios")
Call<SoundResponse> saveSound(
         @Part MultipartBody.Part audioFile,
          @Query("auth_token") String authToken);
```

and

```
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("audio/type", file);  
 GeoService.saveSound(body, SoundResponseCallback,  
    getAuthToken());
```