# POSTing an audio file with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipart

The problem is this. I am sending a music file. I keep getting error `422`. For this reason, it seems I am not able to properly position my body

[image]
this is my output from the console

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Disposition: form-data; 
name="audio[file]"; filename="tr.mp3""
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Content-Length: 6028060
```

and my code

```
@Multipart
@Headers({"Content-Type: multipart/form-data;", "Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*"})
@POST("audios")
Call<SoundResponse> saveSound(@Part ("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"audio[file]\"; filename=\"tr.mp3\"") RequestBody file,
                              @Query("auth_token") String authToken);
```

and called this method

```
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/mpeg"), file);

        GeoService.saveSound(body,SoundResponseCallback, getAuthToken());
```

I also found this stuff
[Send file to server via retrofit2 as object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39078192/send-file-to-server-via-retrofit2-as-object)

**It seems to me that the problem is that the field looks like this "audio** [file]"

Thank you for your help

Comment: You mean you're sending an audio file, not requesting it from the server?

Comment: so i send the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found the answer to the question.The solution was that the file had to be converted to bytes

```
 private void sendFile(Uri data) {
    mParent.showProgress();
    MultipartBody.Part file = packFile(view.getContext(), "audio[file]", data);
    GeoService.saveSound(file, SoundResponseCallback, getAuthToken());
}

@Nullable
public static MultipartBody.Part packFile(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull String partName, @Nullable Uri fileUri) {
    if (fileUri == null) return null;
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    String tp = cr.getType(fileUri);
    if (tp == null) {
        tp = "audio";
    }
    try {
        InputStream iStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
        byte[] inputData = getBytes(iStream);
        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(tp), inputData);
        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, fileUri.getLastPathSegment(), requestFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Nullable
private static byte[] getBytes(@Nullable InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    if (inputStream == null) return null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}
```