# Why not show posts from server when use Retrofit in Android

Tags: android, android-adapter, retrofit2, android-json

I want to use `Retrofit` to load data from server, and I use `DataModel` for set and get data.

This is what I would like to do. When I click on a Category, I want to see posts from this category in the other `Activity`.

For showing category posts I use this link : http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_category_posts

For filtering I use `category id`.

For example : http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_category_posts&id=1 by this link i see all of posts from Category1.

My `Retrofit interface` for set link: (I set `base_url` in **other class**)

```
public interface Retrofit_ApiInterface {

    // For Categories Response
    @GET("tafrihgah/?json=get_category_posts&")
    Call<R_CatModelResponse> getCatResponse(@Query("id") Integer id);
}
```

I send category id to other activity by this code :

```
    public class ColoniesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ColoniesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private List<Retrofit_ColoniesModel> mDateSet;
        private Context mContext;
        private SparseBooleanArray expandState = new SparseBooleanArray();

        public ColoniesAdapter(Context context, List<Retrofit_ColoniesModel> dataSet) {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.mDateSet = dataSet;
            for (int i = 0; i < mDateSet.size(); i++) {
                expandState.append(i, false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.colonies_row, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            holder.colonies_title.setText(mDateSet.get(position).getTitle());
            holder.colonies_title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos = holder.getPosition();
                    Retrofit_ColoniesModel model = mDateSet.get(pos);
                    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), Category_page.class)
                            .putExtra("categoryTitle", model.getTitle())
                            .putExtra("categoryID", model.getId()));

                    Toast.makeText(mContext, " " + model.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

...
```

**Category_page code:**

```
public class Category_page extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final long RIPPLE_DURATION = 250;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TextView toolbar_title;
    private ImageView toolbar_menuImage;
    private RelativeLayout root;
    private CategoryAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView cat_recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private RelativeLayout loadLayout;
    private String catTitle = "";
    private Integer catID;
    private Bundle bundle;
    private int pageCount = 1;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.category_page);
        //if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
        //   EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        //}

        // Hide StatusBar color
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

        // Initializing
        context = Category_page.this;
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.category_toolbar);
        cat_recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.category_recycler);
        toolbar_title = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_pages_title);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.category_root);
        loadLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.category_empty_layout);
        // Toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        }

        // Receive Data
        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        catID = bundle.getInt("categoryID");
        if (bundle != null) {
            catTitle = bundle.getString("categoryTitle");
        }
        if (catTitle != null) {
            toolbar_title.setText(catTitle);
        }

        // Load data
        //LoadData(catID);
        // Menu
        View guillotineMenu = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, null);
        root.addView(guillotineMenu);
        toolbar_menuImage = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_pages_logo);
        new GuillotineAnimation.GuillotineBuilder(guillotineMenu, guillotineMenu.findViewById(R.id.menu_layout_image), toolbar_menuImage)
                .setStartDelay(RIPPLE_DURATION)
                .setActionBarViewForAnimation(toolbar)
                .setClosedOnStart(true)
                .build();
        // RecyclerView
        cat_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        cat_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // Retrofit //////////
        Retrofit_ApiInterface apiInterface = Retrofit_ApiClient.getClient().create(Retrofit_ApiInterface.class);
        Call<R_CatModelResponse> call = apiInterface.getCatResponse(catID);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<R_CatModelResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<R_CatModelResponse> call, Response<R_CatModelResponse> response) {
                List<R_CatModel> models = response.body().getCat_posts();

                mAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(context, cat_recyclerView, models);
                cat_recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                Toast.makeText(Category_page.this, "Response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<R_CatModelResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                Toast.makeText(Category_page.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

I send category_id with below code from one adapter :

```
mContext.startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), Category_page.class)
        .putExtra("categoryTitle", model.getTitle())
        .putExtra("categoryID", model.getId()));
```

and receive this data with below code :

```
// Receive Data
bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
catID = bundle.getInt("categoryID");
```

But **Error message** (`Toast`) instead of **category posts**!

show error toast from :

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<R_CatModelResponse> call, Throwable t) {
    Toast.makeText(Category_page.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Update :** 
This is the error I get, :

```
E/CatResponseError: Error : com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 48 path $.category
```

**Update #2 :** 
Added my POJO class :

```
public class R_CatModelResponse {

    @SerializedName("status")
    public String Cat_status;
    @SerializedName("count")
    public int Cat_count;
    @SerializedName("pages")
    public int Cat_pages;
    @SerializedName("category")
    public List<Retrofit_ColoniesModel> category;
    @SerializedName("posts")
    public List<R_CatModel> Cat_posts;

    public String getCat_status() {
        return Cat_status;
    }

    public void setCat_status(String cat_status) {
        Cat_status = cat_status;
    }

    public int getCat_count() {
        return Cat_count;
    }

    public void setCat_count(int cat_count) {
        Cat_count = cat_count;
    }

    public int getCat_pages() {
        return Cat_pages;
    }

    public void setCat_pages(int cat_pages) {
        Cat_pages = cat_pages;
    }

    public List<Retrofit_ColoniesModel> getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(List<Retrofit_ColoniesModel> category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public List<R_CatModel> getCat_posts() {
        return Cat_posts;
    }

    public void setCat_posts(List<R_CatModel> cat_posts) {
        Cat_posts = cat_posts;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From response you getting a category as a array not a object check your POJO class you defined category as a object. change it to list

Comment: @MohammadNouri `R_CatModelResponse` is your POJO class.

Comment: can you show your pojo class `R_CatModelResponse` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960627/android-retrofit-design-patterns) pattern which make your life easier:D, based on that use following structure:

Your data model should be:

```
public class Model {

    String status;
    int count;
    int page;
    Category category;
    List<Post> posts;

    // implement rest of thing

    public class Category{

        int id;
        String slug;
        String title;
        String description;
        int parent;
        int post_count;
    }

    public class Post {
        int id;
        String type;
        String slug;
        //..rest of thing
    }

}
```

Your service `interface` should be:

```
public interface IService {

        @GET("/tafrihgah/?json=get_category_posts")
        Call<Model> getCategoryPost(
                @Query("id") String id

                //...other query if you need should added like below
               @Query("categorySlug") String categorySlug,
               @Query("tag") String tag,
        );
    }
```

And your `ServiceHelper` contains following method:

```
public Call<CategoryModel> getAllCategory() {
    return service.getCateogryPost();
}
```

And your error cause your `POJO` is not fitted to server Model. Double check your Model and make sure `Object` instead of `List/Array`;

In your case instead of `List<Retrofit_ColoniesModel> category` use `Retrofit_ColoniesModel category`;

Comment: salam, amir jan id telegram dari?

Comment: @MohammadNouri Hi dear Mohammad, Please explain your problem here and I really happy to help you to solve your issue, I Also test your request I get successful.

Comment: Amir jan man ham linke json ro qarar dadam ham POJO class ro. mishe kami vazeh tar befarmaiid ke che taqirati bayad bedam? mamnoon misham rahnamaiim konid

Comment: Off-course Dear Mohammad, As I see your POJO you use List<Category> while your category is not List and it's simple Object. look at my Model class and category attribute.

Comment: mishe code balaiie man ro edit konid ta behtar motavajeh besham chiro bayad eslah konam?

Comment: instead of **List<Retrofit_ColoniesModel> category** use **Category category**

Comment: Got it? Just remove Your List, you don't need it. As error said it's Object not List;

Comment: Faqaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaat haaaaaaaamin?!!!! az sobhe dar gire inam! Thaaaaaanks a lot my dear friend, thanks <3